# Custom Page in Magento2

Tags: magento2, jquery

I am new to Magento 2. We are currently in the process of migrating from Magento 1 and I have been tasked with updating our custom pages to work in Magento 2. I have a page (using the page editor in the admin) that uses it's own styles, jquery and javascript. I have added the files to our template folders and am pulling them in using the xml:

```
<head>
<css src="css/active.min.css" />
<css src="css/apps.min.css" />
<script src="js/active.min.js" />
<script src="js/apps.min.js" />
</head>
```

The files are showing properly in google inspector and are pulling the code when I check them, the css works however none of the js does.

Our developers suggested building a custom module but no matter how much documentation I read I am just not understanding how the Magento 2 modules work. Is there a way to get this to work with template files? I did this the same way with a category and static block and it worked just fine.

Thanks,
Niki

Answer (score 0):

You can make a page_layout in wich the scrip is implemented.
You do this in your Theme. 
contact me for further help

Comment: Thank you I will try this. in the <script> above the linked file is actually .js not .css that was a typo. I may reach out for further assistance.